# JNI get ConcurentHashMap

Tags: java, xamarin, binding, java-native-interface, signature

I need to get access to class field of type

```
ConcurrentHashMap<byte[], BlockingQueue<byte[]>>
```

I am trying to do so by

```
JNIEnv.GetFieldID(class_ref, "queuesMap", "some_signature");
```

but I have no idea what signature it would be. Whatever I try it always says that type can not be found.
What signature should I use?
It is Xamarin binding project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer is:

```
"Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap;"
```

Note: semicolon is important :)

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, glad you found it. You can accept your own answer by now so people can see it has been answered correctly.